# Using overloaded input operator with this pointer

Tags: c++, this, operator-keyword

I couldn't find answer to my question, so here it goes. I created class with overloaded >> operator. Later in code, I've got a method which uses the same code, so I wanted to use overloaded operator with this pointer, but it seems it's not that easy. I wonder what's the problem here and how to solve it in elegant form.

Code:

```
class Zadanie
{
    int rozmiar;
    vector<int> dane;
public:

Zadanie(int _rozmiar = 0)
{
    rozmiar = _rozmiar;
    dane.reserve(rozmiar);
}

int getRozmiar()              { return rozmiar; }
void setRozmiar(int _rozmiar) { rozmiar = _rozmiar;}

friend istream & operator >> (istream & StrmWe, Zadanie & zadanie)
{
    StrmWe >> zadanie.rozmiar;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < zadanie.rozmiar; i++)
    {
        int tmp;
        StrmWe >> tmp;
        zadanie.dane.push_back(tmp);
    }

    return StrmWe;
}

void WczytajDaneZPliku()
{
    const char* filepath = "data0.txt";
    ifstream plik(filepath);
    //plik.open(filepath, ios::in);

    if(plik.good())
        plik >> this;

    plik.close();
}
```

};

Error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream}' and 'Zadanie* const')

I'm looking forward for someone, who will reveal this mystery for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you `operator >>()` takes a `Zadanie` you can use `plik >> *this;`.  `*this` dereferences the pointer and gives you the underlying object.

Comment: Yeah, that's the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You must refer to `*this`:

```
    if(plik.good())
        plik >> *this;
```

Alternatively, call the operator explicitly:

```
    if(plik.good())
        operator>>(plik, *this);
```